# How to retain DropdownButton value during navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was implementing the `DropdownButton` in a flutter project and replicated the code on their dev page [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html). While it works perfectly (In my case, allows me to cycle through a bunch of icons), but if I switch over to another tab in the app and come back to the tab where the `DropdownButton` exists, it resets to it's initial value `List.first`. How can I retain the selected state and change it only when the user changes the value in the app?

Thanks in advance for any advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

To retain the value of `Dropdownbutton` during navigation in flutter,
you can save selected value in stateful widget's state and use that value
to initialize `DropDownButton` when it is rebuilt.

```
  class MyDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDropdownButtonState createState() => _MyDropdownButtonState();
}

class _MyDropdownButtonState extends State<MyDropdownButton> {
  String _selectedValue = 'Option 1';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: _selectedValue,
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(value: 'Option 1', child: Text('Option 1')),
        DropdownMenuItem(value: 'Option 2', child: Text('Option 2')),
        DropdownMenuItem(value: 'Option 3', child: Text('Option 3')),
      ],
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedValue = value!;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Use the `MyDropdownButton` widget in your Scaffold and wrap it with a `ValueListenableBuilder`. The `ValueListenableBuilder` listens for changes to a `ValueNotifier` and rebuilds the `DropdownButton` when the value changes

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<String> selectedValue = ValueNotifier('Option 1');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
        valueListenable: selectedValue,
        builder: (context, value, _) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              MyDropdownButton(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  selectedValue.value = MyDropdownButtonState()._selectedValue;
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second');
                },
                child: Text('Go to Second Screen'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you navigate to new screen save the selected value in a `ValueNotifier` and pass it as an argument of new screen and when navigating back to the first screen, update the selectedValue `ValueNotifier` with the saved in the second screen.

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<String> selectedValue;

  SecondScreen({required this.selectedValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(selectedValue.value),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                selectedValue.value = MyDropdownButtonState()._selectedValue;
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Go back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply, this is so beautifully explained but I don't know if am unable to see if it helps my objective. I am trying to make an Expense tracker where the user can select a currency symbol on the home screen from a dropdown button. I want the selected icon to stay until the user changes it. Is there a better approach to this? like saving it on hive or something?